# How can I implement a typewrite mode in a Tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter

Im on Python 3.9 on Windows 10, and im building a text editor app. Id like to have a typewriter mode where the current text stays centred on the screen and finished/written text scrolls up the screen.
I have tried googling every variation of what that could be called or how to implement it. Ive also looked through 3 or 4 different tutorials and all the docs on every parameter of every method in Tkinters widgets. Im not asking for a complete code snippet necessarily, but im stumped as to how im going to do this.
Thanks for any help received, itd be much appreciated, even a nudge in the right direction.
Chris

Comment: You can try putting the `tk.Text` inside a `tk.Canvas` so you can move it. You can bind to `"<Return>"` (the user pressing the Enter key) and `"<Key>"` (the user pressing any key in general)

Comment: While you write in a Text widget, the text will always be visible. In order to scroll, however, it needs to exend beyond the lower bound of the text widget. So, you can't keep the text centered while you write a text. The cursor at the end of new text will always be on the last line. Unless you insert `h/2`empty lines at the end of the text, where `h` is the height of the Text widget. Then, you can always keep the current entry centered, even if it's at the end of the document. Just remove the newlines when storing the text.